# JSON.parse(), why this escape character returns an error?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to learn more about the core functionality of the JSON.parse() method, but I cannot understand why this string returns an error:

```
JSON.parse('["foo\\"]');  // > "Unexpected end of input"
```

Why does this not return ["foo\"]?

Answer (score 0):

Because the string isn't terminated, because the second `"` is escaped by `\`, because the data you're parsing is:

```
["foo\"]
```

You can confirm this yourself with

```
var s = '["foo\\"]';
alert(s);  // or
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the cumulative escape action of `\` in JS and JSON level in your expression.

Your string `["foo\\"]`

1. Escaped by JS to be `["foo\"]` first because its double `\\`
2. Now it is sent to JSON.parse like `["foo\"]` which escapes the `"`

So, it is an un-terminated string for JSON parser.

If you need to parse `["foo\\"]` in json level, assemble the js string to be escaped to this. Which is `["foo\\\\\"]`.

TEST.

```
s = '["foo\\\\\"]';
console.log(s);               //'["foo\\"]'
console.log(JSON.parse(s);)   // ["foo\"]
```